# Emulating Android Presentation Dialog

Tags: android

I am developing android application with using Presentation feature.

But I don`t have device to test this.

How can I emulate remote display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your Android 4.2+ Android device, you can go into Settings > Developer Options > Simulate secondary displays, to toggle an overlay that will simulate an external display. This works better on tablets than phones, simply because you have more screen space to work with.

This also works with some emulator images, but not all. IIRC, the Android 4.2 x86 emulator image works (at least with Host GPU mode enabled), but 4.3 and 4.4. do not.

I go into somewhat more details on this in [this free excerpt](http://challenges.s3.amazonaws.com/silicon_image/ExternalDisplay-1stEd.pdf) from [my book](http://commonsware.com/Android).

Comment: Thank you! I did not even know about such option!

Comment: hey @Commonsware your chapter is excellent! Can't wait to implement a PresentationFragment! I have one question though, is the opposite route possible? Is it as relatively straightforward as it sounds to move my ViewPager that relies on a FragmentStatePagerAdapter inside the presentation dialog without having to mess too much with the contexts?

Comment: @rupps: Since external displays have no touch interface, there is little point in putting a `ViewPager` in a `Presentation`. After all, the user cannot interact with it.

Comment: @Commonsware yes, it will be remote controlled via the tablet. My question is more technical about fragment, contexts, etc, the usability thing is solved independently!

Comment: @rupps: Well, I can tell you that nested fragments work with a `PresentationFragment`. But I have not tried a `ViewPager` of any form in a `Presentation`, so I cannot comment on how well that will hold up. In theory, it should be OK.